# Hiding undefined values from an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to ask how can I not show something if its undefined on an embed
For example:

```
.addField(`Something`, `1kill: ` + kills + `2kill: ` + kills2)
```

How can I hide 2kill: + kills2 if kills2 was undefined and show 1kill: kills?

*I don't want to hide the whole field, Only what's undefined*

Answer (score 1):

Can you define a variable on the line before?

```
const kill1 = typeof kills != undefined ? `1kill: ` + kills : ''
const kill2 = typeof kills2 != undefined ? `2kill: ` + kills2 : ''
```

Or else you can use string interpolation and use the ternary inside you backticks using `${ternary}` syntax

Answer (score 0):

One approach for this would be to use the ternary operator.
[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
.addField(`Something`, `1kill: ${kills} ${kills2 ? `2kill: ${kills2}` : ''}`);
```

Comment: This should only hide kills2. You would have to do the same thing with `1kill` if you want to hide it too